# how to get max value/highest value from query?

Tags: laravel

i want to get max value/highest value from this query  that include item_name

this show value of

> [{"item_name":"accessories","items":"1"},{"item_name":"assets","items":"6"},{"item_name":"licenses","items":"1"}]

```
     $max_fixassets = DB::table('assets')
    ->select('item_name')
    ->where('item_type','!=','Consumables')
    ->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(item_quantity) as items'))
    ->groupBy('item_name')
    ->get();
```

Blade

```
   {!!json_encode($max_fixassets)!!}
```

Update: did try other method i did get max value but now problem is the item name when try putting

->select('item_name')

in query gives me wrong max value

```
 $query_item = DB::table('assets')
    ->where('item_type','!=','Consumables')
    ->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(item_quantity) as items'))
    ->groupBy('item_name')
    ->get();

   $get_array=array();

    foreach($query_item as $query_item)
    {
        $get_array[]=$query_item;
        $max_fixassets=max($get_array);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**`max('items')`**

```
 $max_fixassets = DB::table('assets')
    ->select('item_name')
    ->where('item_type','!=','Consumables')
    ->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(item_quantity) as items'))
    ->groupBy('item_name')->first();
```

Comment: already tried but gives me this error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items' in 'field list' (SQL: select max(`items`) as aggregate from `assets` where `item_type` != Consumables group by `item_name`)

Comment: just echo $max_fixassets and what r u getting?

Comment: this [{"item_name":"accessories","items":"1"},{"item_name":"assets","items":"6"},{"item_name":"licenses","items":"1"}] without max .. with max function it gives me error

Comment: $max_fixassets = DB::table('assets')
    ->select('item_name')
    ->where('item_type','!=','Consumables')
    ->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(item_quantity) as items'))
    ->groupBy('item_name')->first();